# Android studio Failed to resolve Facebook SDK

Tags: facebook, android-studio

I have an issue in Android studio related to Facebook SDK and it's as below :

[image]

The build.gradle file (Project) looks like this :

```
buildscript {
   repositories {
      mavenCentral()
      jcenter()
  }

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
  }
}

allprojects {
   repositories {
      jcenter {
         url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/"
         url 'https://maven.google.com'
     }
   }
}
```

The build.gradle file (Module:app) looks like this :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
   compileSdkVersion 27
   buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'

   defaultConfig {
       applicationId "com.xxx.xxx"
       minSdkVersion 15
       targetSdkVersion 27
       versionCode 5
       versionName "1.4"
      }

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
        'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug {
        //minifyEnabled true
        //proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }

}

dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1'
  compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
  compile 'com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:4.+'
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.1'
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.1'
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.0.1'
 }
```

Repositories are well added but i can't figure out the issue.

Many thanks.

Comment: If you are using Facebook sdk for Facebook Login then use this `implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[4,5)'`

Comment: Check your appropriate use of Facebook SDK and add that particular dependency instead of all. Refer this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/downloads/ for more info. 
If you still struggling then report the issue in https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/